# Zendesk SDK Swift iOS JWT Authentication failed

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'd added the Zendesk SDK to an iOS Project built using Swift, the Zendesk API authenticates vs my own auth service generating a JWT token. The authentication seems to work fine since the information of the users using the Support chat is shown in the Support panel.

However when trying to access the Support Articles from the Help Center, it won't show any of the content and returns this error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "Web Password";
    srvr = "avenue8help.zendesk.com";
    sync = syna;
}
```

The JWT Token generated by Zendesk using our own endpoint reflects the right information and the structure required by Zendesk.

Any help would be much appreciated

P.S: Even tried to access the Help Center Info over the API using the given token and wasn't able to access such information

Answer (score 0):

Jorge

I was facing the same issue with Zendesk support SDK.

Solutions :

Update Zendesk pods as per Zendesk Doc. -- https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios_support_sdk/sdk_add#adding-the-sdk-with-cocoapods

Check your jwt token API is working properly or not.

jwt token response must be in this format -- { "jwt": "{your_jwt_token_response}" }

For more clear information, check this -- https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001075248

Check your Zendesk Mobile SDK settings are properly added or not.
Select JWT in the Authentication method.
Add your JWT server URL into the JWT URL section.
Check your iOS code.
Initialization :

```
Zendesk.initialize(appId: "your_appId", clientId: "your_clientId",zendeskUrl: "your_zendesk_url") 
Support.initialize(withZendesk: Zendesk.instance)
```

You can find your app_id, client_id and zendesk_url from your Zendesk dashboard under the Mobile SDK section.
Set identity :

```
let identity = Identity.createJwt(token: id)
Zendesk.instance?.setIdentity(identity)
```

Fetch tickets :

```
let requestListController = RequestUi.buildRequestList()   
navigationController?.pushViewController(requestListController, animated: true)
```